# Where are void container mods located?

Tags: warframe

I would like to get Shotgun Spaz which is listed on the wiki as being found from a void container. Does this mean it drops from any breakable container within a void mission or from a locker? Also, is there a good place to search for these?

What I've been doing is running various tier exterminate missions and exploring with Master Thief and Thief's Wit mods equipped. I have not found any mods drop from a container or from a locker which drove me to ask. Should I be looking for them in derelicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be doing VOID missions. Your best shot at getting it are void survival and defense. I have this mod but I have no idea where I got it from, you may have a good shot at getting it inside of the laser room (need to wallclimb from wall to wall until you reach the top where there is a tube you can jump into, once you reach the top you'll be in a hallway with loot containers and 2 sentry turrets on either end of the room). I recommend using a rifle while trying to get it (I ALWAYS get shotgun mods when I'm using rifles and never actually get rifle mods, but that just might be me going crazy).